# Pass Variable from Script 1 to Script 2 to Script 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sys

I'm trying to write a script which pass a variable from Script 1 to Script 2, then Script 2 pass a variable to Script 3 using subprocess. But I am only get responses from Scripts 1 and 2.

What I am expecting to get out is:

> TOM
>    Dick
>    Harry
>    Hello

But what I'm getting is:

> TOM
>
> Hello

The Code I'm using is:

**Script 1**

```
import subprocess

pythonExecutable = 'C:\\Users\\bradl\\Anaconda2\\envs\\GeoSpatial_3.6\\python.exe'
varTest_1 = "Tom"
program = 'D:\\Training\\FromCommandLine\\Script_2.py'

subprocessList1 = [pythonExecutable, program, varTest_1]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(subprocessList1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out1, err1 = p1.communicate()
print(out1.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Script 2**

```
import sys
import subprocess

pythonExecutable = 'C:\\Users\\bradl\\Anaconda2\\envs\\GeoSpatial_3.6\\python.exe'
program = 'D:\\Training\\FromCommandLine\\Script_3.py'

varTest_2 = sys.argv[1]
print(str(varTest_2).upper())

varTest_3 = "Dick"

subprocessList2 = [pythonExecutable, program, varTest_3]
p2 = subprocess.Popen(subprocessList2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out2, err2 = p2.communicate()
print(out2.decode('utf-8'))
print('Hello')
```

**Script 3**

```
import sys

varTest_4 = sys.argv[1]
print(varTest_4)
print(str(varTest_4).upper())
print('Harry')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It works good to me. I got
TOM
Dick
DICK
Harry

Hello

Comment: Running Python as a subprocess of itself is often a poor solution anyway. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395685/launch-a-python-script-from-another-script-with-parameters-in-subprocess-argume

Comment: Cheers, I'll check that out