# Is there any way to pass values to input prompt to the python script which was called by other python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, parameters, arguments

For better understanding,

**example2.py**

```
    a = raw_input("Enter 1st number: ")
    b = raw_input("Enter 2nd number: ")
    *some code here*
    c = raw_input("Enter 3rd number: ")
    s = a+b+c
    print(s)
```

**example1.py**

```
    import os
    os.system('python example2.py')
    <need logic to address the input prompts in example2.py>
    <something to pass like **python example2.py 1 2 3**>
```

I guess by looking at these scripts you can get it what I'm looking for? Let me explain it once for a better understanding. There are two files `example1.py` and `example2.py`. Now, I called `example1.py` from my shell, which in turn called the other script and waiting for the input.

Notes:

- I can't do anything on `example2.py`, which is not owned by me.
- I'm limited to do changes on `example1.py` and pass arguments to `example1.py`
- I know there will be a process created for `example2.py`, but not sure about passing these arguments to process IO.
- Actual code was different, I crafted `example1.py` and `example2.py` for the sake of understanding.

I couldn't grasp any ideas from these links:

[Launch a python script from another script, with parameters in subprocess argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395685/launch-a-python-script-from-another-script-with-parameters-in-subprocess-argume)

[how to execute a python script file with an argument from inside another python script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python)

Please share your thoughts on this and help me to resolve this. Please don't mind editing the question if it requires. I'm completely new to the module `os`, `subprocess`.

Comment: Use the subprocess module. Open the script using `Popen` & use the `communicate` method to pass strings to the stdin of the process

Comment: Thanks a lot. If possible could you share an example of doing it as an answer? So that others can get most of your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the file to run:

```
a = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
b = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
# code
c = int(input("Enter 3rd number: "))
s = a+b+c
print(s)
```

You can run this file from python using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) module.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'a.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, _ = proc.communicate(bytes("1\n2\n3\n", "utf-8"))
print(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

Which results in:

```
Enter 1st number: Enter 2nd number: Enter 3rd number: 6
```

Read the docs & examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) for more details.

I've upgraded the code to python3 since python2 is EOL.

P.S: I've used `shell=True` here for convenience - but you probably shouldn't

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Python 3, raw_input() was renamed to input().

you can use    **int ( input ( ) )**   in example 2

Comment: Thanks, I knew it. My current project uses python 2 only.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use stdout from one script to feed values into another.
Here is an example using python, the pipe "|" command and stdout. The pipe command redirects output from a file and uses it as input to the next file in the chain

```
python example1.py | example2.py
```

Output from code:

```
Enter 1st number: number is 1
Enter 2nd number: number is 2
```

example1.py code:

```
print(1)
print(2)
```

example2.py code:

```
a = input("Enter 1st number: ")
print("number is",a)

b = input("Enter 2nd number: ")
print("number is",b)
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/