# How to get output type from Popen stdout

Tags: python, types, subprocess, stdout, popen

Am making auto-grader and i cant get output type of 'test_file' from stdout,
Like my test_file return integer but stdout always as string
ps. If my code is not good or there is a better way, please suggest me.

```
    def check_output(test_file, result_file, in_type, out_type, input):
        if check_type(in_type, input):
            process1 = Popen(["python", test_file], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
            process1.stdin.write(str(input).encode())
            stdout = process1.communicate()[0]
            output1 = stdout.decode()
            print("Test: " + output1)
            if check_type(output1, out_type):
                print("YES")
    
    
    def check_type(type1, type2):
        return type(type1) == type(type2)
```

Comment: Printed output doesn't *have* a type. You'll have to change how you interact with the code you're grading if you want type information.

Comment: Are you running python 2 or 3? In 3, the stdout of the process is a byte stream. A program can't write an integer to stdout, in fact it needs to be some byte serialized version of the integer. Perhaps that's 8 bytes little endian. In that case the `ctypes` module would help. Can you show us what `print("Test: " + output1)` displayed? Better yet, don't decode stdout and show us the raw bytes. Also, what did the program write and what did you expect to get?

Comment: i expect to compare stdout from test_file and result_file, it work when output from two file are string but not int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like when reading from any other type of file handle, the only possible result from reading standard output is either binary `bytes`, or a `str`, when the bytes are being decoded - either because you used `text=True` or its obsolescent synonym `universal_newlines=True` when invoking `subprocess.Popen()`, or because you explictily `.decode()` the `bytes`, like you do in your code.

There are a couple of other issues with your code. You should generally avoid `Popen` when you can; your code simply remiplements `subprocess.check_output()` or its modern replacement `subprocess.run()` rather clunkily. Secondly, calling Python as a subprocess of Python is very often an antipattern. Unless you are seeking specifically to test that standard output from Python contains what you expect (which, as discussed above, can only be a stream of bytes or characters) you are probably better off doing an `import` of the code and calling the function you want to test, in which case of course it will return a native Python data type by way of its `return` statement, if that's how it's defined.

Comment: that mean i should use another function right ?, thank you.

Comment: Broadly speaking, yes. We can't see what's inside the other script so we don't know what its functions are called. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395685/launch-a-python-script-from-another-script-with-parameters-in-subprocess-argume/48401774#48401774